# How do i return multiple multi-choice list fields in order to get their choice values?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api

Newbie here. Basic REST question for you. I have a list with over a hundred columns. I would like to use REST to retrieve the multi-choice options for two columns but I can't figure out how to do it. I've tried everything i can think of. The first URL below works but the second does not. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl+"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('TESTlist')/fields/GetByTitle('ChoiceFieldOne')";

_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl+"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('TESTlist')/fields/GetByTitle('ChoiceFieldOne','ChoiceFieldTwo')";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a filter to get the fields you want from the fields collection for the list

```
_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('TESTlist')/fields?$filter=(Title eq 'ChoiceFieldOne') or (Title eq 'ChoiceFieldTwo')
```